# Validation of BST using Morris

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is my first post on Stackoverflow. Please forgive me if my post format is not correct. I will try to learn as quick as possible. :)

So recently I am learning about BST. And I am practicing my skills on validating if a given Binary Tree is really a BST(duplicates are allowed as right child.) I tried recursion method and it works but the performance is not as good as I expected for a large given tree. So I tried to use Morris Algorithm to do the work. First I do an in-order traverse to see if the given tree is a BST. Then, I need to validate if all the duplicates are actually the right children of their parents. However, I am stuck on how to make that happen. So I am wondering if someone can give me some hints on that please? Or there's other ways to do that? Thank you very much.

The following are my currently code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

struct Node {
int key;
int left;
int right;

Node() : key(0), left(-1), right(-1) {}
Node(int key_, int left_, int right_) : key(key_), left(left_), right(right_) {}
};

bool IsBST(vector<Node> S) {
vector<size_t> result;
vector<size_t> check;
size_t cur_pos = 0;
size_t pre_pos = 0;
if (!S.size()) {
    return true;
}
while (cur_pos != -1) {
    size_t nxt_left_child = S[cur_pos].left;
    if (nxt_left_child == -1) {
        result.push_back(S[cur_pos].key);
        check.push_back(cur_pos);
        cur_pos = S[cur_pos].right;
    }
    else {
        pre_pos = S[cur_pos].left;
        while (S[pre_pos].right != -1 && S[pre_pos].right != cur_pos) {
            pre_pos = S[pre_pos].right;
        }
        if (S[pre_pos].right == -1) {
            S[pre_pos].right = cur_pos;
            cur_pos = S[cur_pos].left;
        }
        else {
            S[pre_pos].right = -1;
            result.push_back(S[cur_pos].key);
            check.push_back(cur_pos);
            cur_pos = S[cur_pos].right;
        }
    }
}

if (std::is_sorted(result.begin(), result.end())) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (result[i] == result[i + 1]) {
            int temp = S[check[i]].right;
            if (S[temp].key != S[check[i+1]].key) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have code available? The tree (node) definition and the function itself would be the most important to show.

Comment: oh, I am sorry I forgot the most important part. I was thinking I might just need a hint on the direction. :)